# Using apply function on a matrix with NA entries

Tags: r

I read Data from a csv file. If I see this file in R, I have:

```
  V1 V2  V3 V4  V5 V6 V7
1 14 25  83 64 987 45 78
2 15 65 789 32  14 NA NA
3 14 67  89 14  NA NA NA
```

If I want the maximum value in each column, I use this:

```
apply(df,2,max)
```

and this is the result:

```
 V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7 
 15  67 789  64  NA  NA  NA
```

but it works on the column that has no `NA`. How can I change my code, to compare columns with `NA` too?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You just need to add `na.rm=TRUE` to your apply call.

```
apply(df,2,max,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Note: This does assume every column has at least one data point. If one does not `sum` will return `0`.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

`fft` does not have an `na.rm` argument. Therefore, you will need to write your own function.

```
apply(df,2,function(x){fft(x[!is.na(x)])})
```

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(5,5,5))
df[,3] <- NA

> df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  5  5 NA  5  5
2  5  5 NA  5  5
3  5  5 NA  5  5
4  5  5 NA  5  5
5  5  5 NA  5  5

> apply(df,2,function(x){fft(x[!is.na(x)])})
$X1
[1] 2.500000e+01+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i
[5] 1.776357e-15+0i

$X2
[1] 2.500000e+01+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i
[5] 1.776357e-15+0i

$X3
complex(0)

$X4
[1] 2.500000e+01+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i
[5] 1.776357e-15+0i

$X5
[1] 2.500000e+01+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i 1.776357e-15+0i
[5] 1.776357e-15+0i
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but If I use `apply(df,2,fft,na.rm=TRUE)` I get an error:`Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument(s) (na.rm = TRUE)` It seems, that it is not working with FFT ( with others like max,...) it works fine

Comment: Look at `?apply`: the arguments after FUN (e.g. `max` or `fft`) are passed to FUN. And `fft` does not have a `na.rm` parameter, therefore you get an error. You can use `na.omit()` on the column first, and then `fft`.

Comment: @TangoStar It's Dayne - not Dayana - but I am unsure what you mean. Why would you want to use a for loop when apply works?

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
sapply(apply(df,2,na.exclude), fft)
```

EDIT: the code above may fail if `apply()` returns a matrix instead of a list. And this will happen if there are no `NA`s for instance. The code below fixes that:

```
sapply(tapply(m, col(m), na.exclude), max)
```

Interesting, there is no need to set `simplify=FALSE`, as the result of `tapply()` will only be simplified if `na.exclude()` returns a single scalar per column; and in this case `sapply` works in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the following:

```
apply(na.omit(df),2,max)
```

**na.omit(df)** will simply remove incomplete cases from each column of your data frame **df** and then the **apply()** function will yield the max value for each of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, this will return `-Inf` if all elements of col are NA

```
df<-structure(list(x = c(10, 12, 13), y = c(12, 13, NA), z = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

kk<-Map(function(x) max(na.omit(df[,x])),as.list(names(df)))
ll<-do.call(rbind,kk)
rownames(ll)<-names(df)

> ll

 [,1]
x   13
y   13
z -Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a result of a posterior version but you could actually do:

```
apply(df,2,function(x) max(x,na.rm=T))
```

which will return you a vector or equivalently:

```
lapply(df,function(x) max(x,na.rm=T))
```

which will return you a list. Notice that whenever one of the columns in df is a character it will fail returning all NA's. In this case you may need to do a prior select of the objective variables.